# Is the unit ball of $C^1[0,1]$ in $C[0,1]$ relatively compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I think I need to use the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem.

It is clear that the unit ball is bounded in $C[0,1]$, but i don't know how to prove (or disprove) equicontinuous.

Comment: What metric are you using in $C^1[0,1]$? $\|x\|_\infty+\|x'\|_\infty$?

Comment: What is the metric defining the "unit ball"? If it is the $\sup$-norm of the function, then it is not true. If it is the $\sup$-norm of the function plus the $\sup$-norm of its derivative, it is

Comment: yes, it is the $\|x\|_\infty + \|x'\|_\infty$

Comment: Equicontinuity follows from the fact that $\ x'\ $ is uniformly bounded, but you need more than uniform boundedness and equicontinuity for compactness.  You also need closure with respect to the sup-norm topology.